# Wildfly 8 logging, how to truncate logger name from the left?

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

My application is running in Wildfly 8.2.1. In the `standalone.xml` file, the logging subsystem is configured to use the following pattern-formatter:

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} | %-5p | %-15.15t | %-30.30c | %s%n%e"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
```

When the logger's name has more than 30 characters, it's truncated from the right, like in the line bellow (where the full logger name is `com.fakeorg.test.gateway.polling.LongPollingMap`):

```
2017-04-25 11:45:00,010 | DEBUG | EJB default - 1 | com.fakeorg.test.gateway.polli | Begin removing expired long-polling connections...
```

How to make it truncate from the left when the name is greater than 30 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use `%-30.-30c`. However you'd run into a [truncation issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-141).

You could replace the `org.jboss.logmanager` module with a newer version though. It doesn't look like the correct version of the log manager made it into to WildFly until WildFly 11.0.0.Alpha1.

To replace the module you'd need to [download 1.5.7.Final](https://repository.jboss.org/org/jboss/logmanager/jboss-logmanager/1.5.7.Final/jboss-logmanager-1.5.7.Final.jar) of the log manager, place it in the `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/` directory and edit the `module.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.jboss.logmanager">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-logmanager-1.5.7.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Very good. I don't know if I really want to replace the module because I had a bad time in the past migrating the code from JBossAS to Wildfly because there was too many modules replaced and custom modules installed.

Comment: It should be pretty safe in this specific case.