# Wildfly stack trace logging format prepends war name

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-logging

I have recently upgraded `Wildfly server` version from `wildfly-10.1.0.Final` to `wildfly-24.0.0.Final`, post that I could see a logging message format change specifically for error stack-trace. The `war` filename gets **prefixed** in every line of stack trace which was not there in the version of `wildfly-10.1.0.Final`. I have analyzed the logging pattern and log manager configuration but there is no other change, however, wondering what caused the stack-trace logging format change and how to get rid of the war filename from the stack-trace

An excerpt from the log stack trace

```
2021-11-03 01:12:22,954 ERROR [com.demo.GenericExceptionMapper] (default task-22084) Message:: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException -- ErrorCode:: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:767)
    at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers$PostWrapper$1.handleRequest(RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers.java:71)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.predicate.PredicatesHandler.handleRequest(PredicatesHandler.java:141)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers$PreWrapper$1.handleRequest(RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers.java:52)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Even the logging manager, pattern-formatter is same for both of the Wildfly server versions

```
 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
```

**wildfly-10.1.0.Final**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="app.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="ERROR"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

**wildfly-24.0.0.Final**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="app.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="ERROR"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

the only change is the version of XML namespace of `urn:jboss:domain:logging`. Moreover, couldn't see any change in [pattern-formatter](https://docs.wildfly.org/24/Admin_Guide.html#pattern-formatter) spec as well

Comment: It looks like you likely upgraded the Java version you're using which prints the stack traces like that.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, the Java version will not likely be a trouble maker, because even before the upgrade `wildfly-10.1.0.Final` was running on the jdk11 version

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I could see your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663777/3303074) regarding the logging, is there any simple alternative to logmanager `org.jboss.logmanager`

Comment: That is just how it's formatted with Java 11 and recent versions of the log manager. If you do `Throwable.printStackTrace()` you'll see the same thing. The only way to leave off the module would be to use Java 8.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, is this because of https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-5259, because of new changes in stack trace causes larger occupancy of log storage, is there a way to avoid it? any configuration-based workaround?

Comment: No I don't think it was that specific upgrade. I'm not sure what version it was fixed in off the top of my head. However, the module being added is a result of `StackTraceElement.toString()`. There is currently no way to configure this via configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JamesR.Perkins